# Проблема с роутингом в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Решил изучить php фрэймворк - Yii2.
Но столкнулся с проблемой роутинга.

Вот что у меня есть:

*config/web.php*

```
...
'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/say',
                'site/contact' => 'site/say'
            ]
        ],
...
```

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

*controllers/SiteController.php*

```
...

    public function actionSay($message = 'Привет')
    {
        return $this->render('say', ['message' => $message]);
    }
...
```

*views/site/say.php*

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
$this->title = 'Say';
?>
<?= Html::encode($message) ?>
```

Корень `localhost` указывает на директорию `basic/web`. По запросу `localhost` всё нормально запускается, отображается шаблон `say`, но по запросу `localhost/site/contact` выводится ошибка 404, страница не найдена.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А .htaccess в папке web лежит?

Comment: да, именно там!

Comment: А дебаггер работает? внизу страницы который. Там может можно что увидеть.

Comment: уже нашёл решение. просто apache2 не позволял применять .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

нашёл решение.

необходимо было ещё правильно настроить apache2 в файле apache2.conf в описании настроек директории надо было указать AllowOverride All, примерно так

```
<Directory /home/.../basic/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

это позволяет применять всё, что написано в .htaccess